# Ionic, servico, como criar uma task

Tags: javascript, android, ios, ionic, angular

gostaria de saber se é possível criar um servico no ionic, que fique executando mesmo com o app em segundo plano e que de em determinados momentos execute uma método como se fosse um setTimeout mas sempre ativo.

Comment: Dá uma olhada no plugin background-mode do Cordova: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-mode/

Comment: interessante, vou analisar